# Setting a timer for my game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, timer, html5-canvas

I'm currently stuck on getting a timer to work on my maze game. I basically want the timer to start straight away and once you reach the end the timer stops.

Here is my current code, I haven't included any code to do with the time as i've being ripping my hair about it. any help would be superbly helpful!

```
var canvas;
var ctx;

var mazeWidth = 510;
var mazeHeight = 510;

var y = 300;
var x = 120;

var maze = new Image();

var collision = 0;

var time = 0

function init() 
{
canvas = document.getElementById('canvasMaze');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
maze.src = "maze.png";
return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() 
{
clear();
ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
rect(x, y, 15,15);

ctx.fillText(time + " seconds",10,50);

if (x <= 15)
{
    var restart = confirm("It took you " + time + " seconds to complete the maze!");
    if (restart == true)
    {
        x = 250;
        y = 250;
        time = 0;           
    }
}
}

function clear() 
{
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mazeWidth, mazeHeight);
ctx.drawImage(maze, 1, 1);
}

function rect(x,y,w,h) 
{
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}

function doKeyDown(e)
{
switch (e.keyCode) 
{
    case 38:
    case 87:
    if (y - 6 > 10)
    {
        y -= 6;
        clear();
        collisionCheck();
        if (collision == 1)
        {
            y += 6;
            collision = 0;
        }
    }
    break;
    case 40: 
    case 83:
    if (y + 6 < 466 )
    {
        y += 6;
        clear();
        collisionCheck();
        if (collision == 1)
        {
            y -= 6;
            collision = 0;
        }
    }
    break;
    case 37:
    case 65:
    if (x - 6 > 0)
    {
        x -= 6;
        clear();
        collisionCheck();
        if (collision == 1)
        {
            x += 6;
            collision = 0;
        }
    }
    break;
    case 39:
    case 68:
    if (x + 6 < 468)
    {
        x += 6;
        clear();
        collisionCheck();
        if (collision == 1)
        {
            x -= 6;
            collision = 0;
        }
    }
    break;
}
}

function collisionCheck()
{
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 18, 18);
var pix = imageData.data;
for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) 
{
    if (pix[i] == 0) 
    {
        collision = 1;
    }
}
}

init();
window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
```

Comment: You should show your attempt, maybe it's just a near-miss.

Comment: My attempts were so bad and frustrating I just ended up removing it all, I've currently looked at other examples, although there are very few I just couldn't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to get the current time at page load or init and perhaps store it in a global variable. Then everytime you call the draw function, you can determine the time elapsed from subtracting the current time from the initial time.

```
var initialTime = new Date();
var lastUpdate = new Date();
var minTime = 100;
function draw()
{
    ...
    var currentTime = new Date();

    //Don't update if enough time has not passed
    if(currentTime - lastUpdate < minTime)
    {
        //Don't update the timer
    }
    else
    {
        //Update the timer
    }

    var timeTaken = currentTime - initialTime;



    if(x <= 15)
    {
        var restart = confirm("It took you " + timeTaken + " seconds to complete the maze!");
    }
    ...
    lastUpdate = Date.Now();
}
```

}

Comment: ‘Date.now()‘ is to be preferred to ‘new Date()‘, since it gives the same result without creating garbage.

Comment: @abbath - Thank you for your comment, it is returning some data, but it seems to be recording it milliseconds or something VERY fast.

Comment: I think javascript Date defaults to milliseconds, so you may want to have a look at some date formatting. It is very fast since you since you specified the draw interval at every 10ms.

Comment: @Abbath - What would be the easiest way to get around the whole 10ms draw interval? would there be a way to slow down the timer without messing with the interval?

Comment: Just add another two variables. `var minTimeToUpdate = 100;` and `var lastUpdate`. Something like `if(currentTime - lastUpdate < minTimeToUpdate) return;` and update `lastUpdate` everytime the if statement is not triggered.

Comment: Could you possibly write an example for me? been stuck on this for a while and I'm close to pulling my eyeballs out!